# Prevent click trigger if user cliks when animating

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a `.box` div and on click it expands.

The problem is if you fast click many times on that div, the click event will trigger the new animation and the animation will run for every click.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="title">
        <label>Some title</label>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <label>Some text that is longer then the title text</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.box').toggle(function() {
    $(this).attr("selected", "true");
    $(this).animate({"height": "529px", "width": "460px"}, "slow");
},function() {
    $(this).animate({"height": "163px", "width": "220px","z-index":"10"}, "slow");
});
```

I want to somehow disable the clicking until the **animation finishes once**.

Is that possible ?

[Click fast many times on the yellow div](http://jsfiddle.net/EZVK3/).

Comment: fyi.. the toggle event handler has been deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9 http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: @wirey what's the alternative for toggle then ?

Comment: toggle just binds to the click event - so you can bind to the click event hand handle it there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.is(':animated')` to check if object is animated at the moment, do it like this for example http://jsfiddle.net/65W2G/:

```
$('.box').toggle( function () {
    if ($(this).is(':animated')) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).attr("selected", "true");      
    $(this).animate({"height": "529px", "width": "460px"}, "slow");
}, function () {
    if ($(this).is(':animated')) {
        return;
    } 
    $(this).animate({"height": "163px", "width": "220px","z-index":"10"}, "slow");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should bind to the click event handler instead of using toggle because it was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed as of jQuery 1.9

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.is(':animated')){
        return false;   // return false if it's already animating
    }
    // determine height/width to animate too
    var height = $this.height() == 529 ? '163px': '529px';
    var width = $this.width() == 460 ? '200px' : '460px';

    $this.attr("selected", "true");
    $this.animate({"height": height, "width": width}, "slow");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TgaAj/)